# Windows 8.1 doesn't prompt for User Credentials when trying to connect with EAP(PEAP, TTLS) configuration using 3rd party WLAN network manager

Tags: security, networking, notifications, wifi

I am using a 3rd party network manager to configure WLAN adapter. Issue is specific to connection with 802.1x security configured access points. I have configured the profile with prompt for User Credentials set to true, but when I try to connect it doesn't prompt for credentials or neither there is any balloon notification. 
In Windows 7 we see a balloon notification like

"Additional Information is needed to connect xxxxprofile, Click here for more information" . When clicked we get a credentials prompt from EAP method.

In Windows 8 we get a prompt, only if configured using default WLAN Autoconfig.

Please clear the following queries:

1) Difference between Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 WLAN Autoconfig.

2) Do i need to change any registry settings for the prompt?

3) Is this issue specific to WLAN network configuration utility or EapHost eap methods?

2) If this needs app support, how to add Credentials prompt support to our application?

Let me know for more details
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As I know (only user experience) is that win7 doesn't have the capability to save login credentials for eap auth mode.
Win8 has the possibility to do. Maybe the 3rd Party WLan manager doesn't work 100% with Win8?

Since we don't have any more detailed information which WLan manager you use, I can only provide a link where the eap credentials prompt configuration is done with Win8 tools:
http://r1.umkc.edu/wireless/Windows8.asp